# What is CoreRAID? What is the function of com.apple.CoreRAID.plist in LaunchDaemons?

Tags: snow-leopard

What is the function of com.apple.CoreRAID.plist in LaunchDaemons? What happens if I disable it? In general terms what is CoreRAID?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

CoreRAID is a [Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html) to manipulate [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) devices.

The *com.apple.CoreRAID.plist* file in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` is used to start the CoreRAIDServer used in managing RAID devices.

Although I do have RAID Attached Storage Devices even if I didn't I would not disable the *com.apple.CoreRAID.plist* so as to be able to work with RAID devices as/when necessary.